# HTML 5 application cache - get the updated date

Tags: html, application-cache

We are planning to use `HTML 5`'s `Application cache` in our application for storing static
content and some documents like a timetable. This timetable gets
updated every week. Now in our application we need to display the *last updated date* of this
timetable.
Is it possible to get the created date or downloaded date of a file which is there in the 
application cache programmatically? Or is there some better way of doing this (we dont' want
to save any information in the server side)? Could you please let me know?

Comment: Can you not just put the date in the timetable?

Comment: If we put the date, then we have to parse the document to find out. The document could be of type pdf/xls/doc

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this approach.  Use a regular AJAX `GET` and look at the `Last-Modified` header:

```
function getTimeStamp(url) {
    var xmlHttpReq = false;
    var self = this;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    self.xmlHttpReq.open('GET', url, true);
    self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
            log(self.xmlHttpReq.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified"));
        }
    }
    self.xmlHttpReq.send(null);
}
```

My [test page](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/offline-timestamp/index.html) seems to be working, but it's late and I may have messed it up.